# Cannot input text after closing a confirm dialog by Esc key

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

After closing a confirm dialog on a page by Esc key, I cannot input any text into any text field on the page. How can I fix it?

This small html should be able to reproduce the problem easily.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<input type="text">
<script>
    window.confirm('hogehoge')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Repro Steps:

1. Open this html to open a confirm dialog above the page.
2. Hit Esc key on keyboard to close the dialog.
3. Click on the text-input field on the page to try input something.

Result:

Caret doesn't show up, and cannot input anything.

Expected:

Can input text into the text-input field.

Notes:

- This repros on Chrome and Edge(chromium).
- Not repro on FireFox.
- OS: Windows10
- Once the focus goes out of the window, this problem disappears.

Comment: I can confirm.  I can TAB and then SHIFT_TAB to get back to the page, but clicking the input won't give it focus. Also happens when F12 console is up and I enter `window.confirm('lkj')` and Esc out. Same behavior.  Odd that clicking the input will NOT give it focus at all.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's a security feature, not a bug:

https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-changes-how-the-escape-key-is-handled-in-chrome-to-fight-popup-ads/

From the article

> "Since users never intend to interact with the page through the ESC
> key, it should not trigger user activation," Google said.

By "user activation" they exclude things like mouse hover or swiping fingers on the screen.

Comment: what a stupid google logic. popup is popup. text input is text input. Fighting popups - it places a bann to interaction with a searchbox - for example.